# Updating q-values in q-learning

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning, q-learning

I have been reading up about Q-learning, and I have a question about how the value iteration is computed.

From my understanding, the algorithm updates the q-value of a state-action pair, after that action has been taken. So let's say that action `a` moves the state from `s` to `s'`. The q-value, `q(s,a)` is equal to the value of being in state `s`, plus the discounted maximum q-value across all actions possible from state `s'`.

However, this seems inefficient to me, because q-values are only updated by looking one step ahead. For example, let's say that the only state that has a reward is state 100, and the agent starts in state 0. When it finally reaches state 100 by random exploration, it will then update the q-value for the state which the agent was in just before it entered state 100.

But this does not update the q-values for state 0. To update this, it will have to update the q-values for all the state-action pairs that create a "link" from states 100 to 0.

Instead, wouldn't it be possible to just "work backwards" from state 100, and update all the q-values for all states from which state 100 can be reached in one step. Then, for each of these states, update the q-values for all the states which can reach these. This would continue until finally, the q-values in state 0 are updated.

Otherwise, the q-values are only ever updated for a state-action pair which are actually selected during exploration, which could take a very long time to converge.

Presumably I am either misunderstanding q-learning, or misunderstanding the practicalities of my proposed solution.... Any help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's a good idea. What you are thinking of is called *eligibility traces*. They often improve convergence speed, but this comes at the cost of significantly greater computation and memory cost, as well as increased complexity. The *Sutton and Barto* book describes them in detail.

Comment: Was just going to add this.  Another issue with eligibility traces is that either you have to do on-policy learning (not ideal) or you have to extinguish traces when exploratory steps are taken (which kills the benefit of traces).

Answer (score 1):

You are right, in some cases it makes sense to do that.

What you suggest is Monte Carlo, which is the same as TD($\lambda$) with $\lambda = 1$.